# Image width on Safari with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am working with javascript and i want to get an image width with prototype. I did :

```
 lastElement.down('img').width
```

It working on firefox but Safari ruturn 0. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lastElement.down('img').getWidth()
```

If you just access `someimg.width` what you're getting is the `width` attribute on the img-tag itself, which may not be set.

See [Prototype's docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/getWidth/) for more

Comment: So, how can i get the width of the image without the width attribute?

Comment: @Sebastien: Like I wrote in my answer; use `getWidth()` which will get the actual width of the element…